# Run Multiple Sql queries asynchronously in Vertx (Vert.x 3)

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, vert.x

I am using vertx-mysql-postgresql-client-3.3.0 and vertx-sql-common-3.3.0
I initially thought of using Batch operation to insert multiple statements but looks like this(http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common/java/#_batch_operations) is not implemented in the vertx-mysql-postgres-client.

The code that handles post data to db is:

```
SQLConnection sqlConnection;
 List <JsonArray> targetParams = new ArrayList();
 for (String key : targetObject.getTargets().keySet()) {
    targetParams.add(new JsonArray().add(key).add(targetObject.getTargets().get(key)).add(targetObject.getId()));
 }
 int[] i = {targetObject.getTargets().size()};
 while(i[0]>=0) {
   sqlConnection.updateWithParams("INSERT INTO Targets (name,  id,language) VALUES (?,?,?)", taglineParams.get(i[0] - 1), result ->
{           
  if (result.succeeded()) {
      i[0]--;
 }

else { badRequest(context, "Error inserting error code: " +   result.cause().toString());
   }
 }); 
}
```

The AsyncResult handler code:

```
Handler<AsyncResult<SQLConnection>> sqlConnectionHandler = new Handler<AsyncResult<SQLConnection>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(AsyncResult<SQLConnection> res) {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            sqlConnection = res.result();
        } else {
            logger.error("Unable to create SQL connection: " + res.cause().toString());
        }
    }
};
```

This one doesn't work and gives Thread Blocked error after inserting first.

Any idea how I can make the multiple inserts work?

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x is an asynchronous framework however the code is using a synchronous construct that will not work. There is a while loop until a variable is greater than 0. but the update to the control variable is updated on a async handler which means that it won't be called inside the loop.

Knowing this the loop will run "forever" until the JVM thread scheduler will stop it to run other thread (which will eventually update the the control var). Now that the scheduler has stopped the thread you will also be notified by Vert.x that you blocked the event loop, which means you should revise your code.

I'd suggest either to concatenate the SQL statement in on big sql statement and execute at once, or use a for loop. Note that the for loop is also not 100% safe. Say that you're inserting 1M rows you can also easily use more than 2s of CPU time and you'll get the warning again.

The good solution would be an async loop or look to RX for example.

Comment: Using for loop also I get the same thread already running issue. Will a query like  `INSERT INTO Targets (name,  id,language) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?);", taglineParams, result -> `
 work?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using CountDownLatch in those situations:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(targetObject.getTargets().size());
for (JsonArray params : targetParams) {
    sqlConnection.updateWithParams("INSERT INTO Targets (name,  id,language) VALUES (?,?,?)", params, result ->
    {
        if (!result.succeeded()) {
            badRequest(context, "Error inserting error code: " +   result.cause().toString());
        }
        latch.countDown();
    });
}

latch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is still bad for Vert.x, as it will block the thread, so you should also consider changing your logic, not to wait for the process to complete at all.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the office API,[batch operation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common/java/#_batch_operations),maybe you can use this.

```
List<JsonArray> batch = new ArrayList<>();
batch.add(new JsonArray().add("joe"));
batch.add(new JsonArray().add("jane"));

connection.batchWithParams("INSERT INTO emp (name) VALUES (?)", batch, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    List<Integer> result = res.result();
  } else {
    // Failed!
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this. When I checked the code it says Operation not supported because it is not implemented.